# QGIS Interpolation on Curved Grid (River DEMs)

Tags: qgis, dem, open-source-gis

I have an very hard task I want to do in QGIS (or another open source GIS program).

I have point data for river bathymetry (depth). I have been creating digital elevation models of them using Grass and masking the river which makes them look gorgeous but I can tell that there are some issues, just logically. GRASS is interpolating in a North-South East-West Grid, which is not he direction the river runs in! The river meanders and turns and the bathymetry must be interpolated accordingly.

The goal would be to draw a line down the center of the river and use that as a guide for the interpolation (to interpolate outwards from the line). I have seen a nice lecture where a professor mathematically straightened the line using a datum and creating a "straightening" equation and then applying it. The interpolation was then done in the traditional way but at the end the river was re-curved. I did not 100% understand it.

Other things worth mentioning are that ideally this software would interpolate new cross sections (Can this be done in HEC-RAS?) I am pretty sure software such as Mike-11 or Mike-Something more advanced can do this but looking for an open source solution.

The questions are:

Does there exist a tool for this currently?

How could I go about creating a tool for this? (Python plugin)?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate new cross sections using Hec-Ras, you draw a line like a center of your river then you need to use the coordinates of your cross sections (I used Covadis software to get them).
this video expalin the process 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlsTNNIi6Kc